# Separate Functions For Finding The Area and Perimeter of a Rectangle Part II

Tags: javascript, html, css, math

So, thanks to a fantastic person here [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar), I completed my code correctly with user input instead of how I made it initially, which was giving the answer of Area and Perimeter at the same time.

But I am being told to separate this into two functions. Essentially, create separate tasks for the Area and Perimeter calculations and pass the length and width parameters.

It works flawlessly and I am just unsure how to separate this wonderful function into several more...

Below is my codepen and code for it if anyone has any suggestions.

With the help of Barmar, I thought I had done a great job with this, but now I am being challenged one last time before midnight to make separate functions from them. Any advice or pointers would be helpful. Thank you.

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/agtshadow/pen/0764f3ef05cfddc5f100fcff8e3010f4)

Code Snippet:

```js
function controller() {
  var type = document.getElementById("apBox").value;
  var length = document.getElementById("lengthBox").value;
  var width = document.getElementById("widthBox").value;
  var mainSolution = document.getElementById("message");
  var answer;
  var label;
  if (type == "a" || type == "A") {
    answer = length * width;
    label = 'Area';
  } else if (type == "p" || type == "P") {
    answer = 2 * length + 2 * width;
    label = 'Perimiter';
  } else {
    mainSolution.innerText = "Invalid. Must Enter 'A' or 'P'";
    return;
  }
  if (length.length > 0 && width.length > 0) {
    if (!isNaN(answer)) {
      mainSolution.innerHTML = `${label} =&nbsp ${answer}`;
    }
  } else {
    mainSolution.innerHTML = "";
  }
}


function clearText() {
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = ("<br>");
  document.getElementById("apBox").value = "";
  document.getElementById("lengthBox").value = "";
  document.getElementById("widthBox").value = "";
}
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: #455A6F;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#header {
  background-color: #292A2B;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  color: rgb(27, 157, 218);
}

.btn1,
.btn2 {
  background-color: rgba(52, 139, 221, 0.699);
  border: #303436;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 3;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px black;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 black;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-shadow: 1px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
}


/* This is a custom snippet I made, so the footer always stays at the bottom of the page */

footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 18px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top: 30em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.description {
  font-style: italic;
}

form {
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta name="description" content="Program 9 Assignment, IS30A, Area of a Rectangle">
  <title>Program 9</title>
</head>
<!-- HTML Body -->

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Program 9</h1>
      <h5>Area or Perimeter</h5>
      <h6>of a Rectangle</h6>
    </div>
    <!-- Main Form & Inputs For User Interaction -->
    <form id="myForm">
      <form id="myForm">
        <label for="userInput1">Enter A for Area or P for Perimeter:</label><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="apBox">
        <br><br>
        <label for="userInput2">Length:</label><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="lengthBox"><br><br>
        <label for="userInput3">Width:</label><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="widthBox">
      </form>
      <!-- Empty Field & Message For User Who Interacted as well as Output: -->
      <p id="demo">Output: </p>
      <p id="message"> <br> </p>
      <!-- Buttons For Submit & Clear Fields Above -->
      <button class="btn1" type="button" onClick="controller()">Submit</button>
      <button class="btn2" type="button" onClick="clearText()">Clear</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
</body>
<!-- End HTML -->

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's actually quite simple to make these their own functions.  Your javascript will look like this:

```
function controller() {
  var type = document.getElementById("apBox").value;
  var length = document.getElementById("lengthBox").value;
  var width = document.getElementById("widthBox").value;
  var mainSolution = document.getElementById("message");
  var answer;
  var label;
  if (type == "a" || type == "A") {
    answer = Area(length, width);
    label = 'Area';
  } else if (type == "p" || type == "P") {
    answer = Perimiter(length, width);
    label = 'Perimiter';
  } else {
    mainSolution.innerText = "Invalid. Must Enter 'A' or 'P'";
    return;
  }
  if (length.length > 0 && width.length > 0) {
    if (!isNaN(answer)) {
      mainSolution.innerHTML = `${label} =&nbsp ${answer}`;
    }
  } else {
    mainSolution.innerHTML = "";
  }
}

function Perimiter(length, width){
  return length * 2 + width * 2
}

function Area(length, width){
  return length * width
}


function clearText() {
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = ("<br>");
  document.getElementById("apBox").value = "";
  document.getElementById("lengthBox").value = "";
  document.getElementById("widthBox").value = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So simple... I just couldn't figure it out. I originally had the page as a Length and Width inputs, and it would give both, but no, it needed user input a third time and separate functions, so I was working with code I had already done and was trying to split up to meet the requirements. Thanks so much again!